# consider the initial value problem $ y'=y^{1/3}, y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider the initial value problem $y'=y^{\frac{1}{3}} , y(0)=0 $ This is already asked
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246676/initial-value-problem-dy-dx-y1-3-y0-0-has-one-of-the-following-solutio)

I have a doubt in those answer, as that question is 6 years old, i ask this seperately.

> 1. Its is written in comment that the function is ill-defined in negative axis. What does it means? Please explain this intuitively
> 2. Also in that accepted answer how answerer got that idea of that function. It's not trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In general, $y \mapsto y^\beta$ with $\beta > 0$ real is only defined for $x\ge0$. How would you define $(-2)^\pi$? This is why the function is said to be ill-defined for $x<0$.
2. To find the solutions of $y^\prime=y^{\frac{1}{3}} , y(0)=0$, you can notice that functions always vanishing on an interval are solutions. And for $y(t) \neq 0$, you can rewrite the equation as 
   $$\frac{y^\prime(t)}{(y(t))^{1/3}} = 1$$ and integrate it on $(\alpha,x)$. You get the solution $y(x) = (2/3)^{3/2} (x-\alpha)^{3/2}$. You then see that the functions

$$y(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ for } x < \alpha \\
(2/3)^{3/2} (x-\alpha)^{3/2} & \text{ for } x \ge  \alpha
\end{cases}$$

are also solutions.

Comment: But $\frac13\neq\pi$, and for $\frac13$ there is a preferred representative of the root also for negative arguments

Comment: you can notice that functions always vanishing on an interval are solutions---- please explain this a little

Comment: @CloudJR Let $y(t)=0$ on an interval. What is $y'$? Well, of course $y'(t)=0$, which happens to coincide with $y(t)^{1/3}=0$. So they are solutions.

Comment: If $y(t) = 0$ for $t \in (a,b)$ then $y^\prime(t) = 0$ also. So $y$ is a solution.

Answer (score 6):

The only reasonable definition of $y^{1/3}$ for $y<0$ in this context is
$$
y^{1/3} = -|y|^{1/3} \qquad \forall y<0.
$$
Whoever claims differently is just confusing people.

The non uniqueness of solutions is related to the non-Lipschitzianity of the function; it has nothing to do with it being "ill-defined in negative axis", whatever that means. You would have the same problem with the ODE $y'=|y|^{1/3}$. What happens on the negative $y$ axis does not matter at all in this exercise.

The example of a parametrized family of solutions starting at $y(0)=0$ is a standard exercise. The key insights are that:

- the ODE is autonomous, so you can translate solutions,
- $y=0$ is a solution,
- you can "join" the $y=0$ solution with any one departing from it.

Comment: In this case we can say that the derivative is not continuous at 0, hence the uniqueness is not necessarily true, and so we must look for other possibilities. If I remember correctly Lipschitz condition is weaker than continuity and differentiability, so your answer is better, I am just confirming.