# Does there exist a unique solution for $y' = -y^{1/3}, y(0) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The given problem is to determine if the following initial value problems have a unique solution :

1. $y' = y^{\frac13}, y(0) = 0,$
2. $y' = -y^{\frac13}, y(0) = 0,$

We can not apply Picard's theorem here. For the first one, the answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246676/662330)  post tells that solutions are infinite.

For the second one, I tried to construct a similar function given in the answer but was not successful. Since only the sign is different in the second one than the first one, I feel that the solutions are infinite but unable to prove or disprove them. Any help is higly appreciated.

Comment: @Surb Can you explain how $y(x) = x^{3/4}$ is a solution? I see that $y' = \frac34 x^{-1/4} \ne -y^{1/3}$

Comment: @VvCh Fine, take instead $y(x)=\frac{4}{3}x^{3/4}$ then

Comment: @K.defaoite Can you again check if $y = (4/3)x^{3/4}$ satisfies the equation? I dont get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second equation *also* has infinitely many solutions, in a very similar form as the infinite family for the first. Let $a<0$, then
$$y(x)=\begin{cases}(2/3)^{3/2}(\color{blue}{a-x})^{3/2}&x\le a\\0&x>a\end{cases}$$
is the desired infinite family.

Comment: I also thought the same function initially but this does not satisfy $y(0) = 0 $ right?

Comment: @VvCh It does, since $a$ is now negative!

Comment: Ok, got it, I was taking $a$ as positive.  Thank you.

Comment: @VvCh don't forget to accept my answer too :)