# Solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=-y^\frac{1}{3} $ and $y(0)=0 $.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-y^\frac{1}{3} $ and
$y(0)=0 $.

Then this Initial value problem has

a) unique solution

b) infinity many solution

c) No solution

My apporach:
Take $y= (-\frac{2}{3}(x-a))^\frac{3}{2}$ if $x\leq a$

And $y=0$ if $x\geq a$
Where a is any negative real no.
It satisfy Initial condition.
It have infinitely many solution for Infinitely many choice of a.
So IVP has infinitely many solution.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: A similar question was asked recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4543015/42969

Comment: Thankyou , i was not able to find that question

Comment: $dx/dy=-y^{-1/3}$ so $x=-\frac32 y^{2/3}+C.$ So $y=(C_1-\frac23 x)^{3/2}.$